# What's the meaning of the phrase "come around" in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I'm watching an anime called "Cowboy Bebop" which takes place in space. In one of the scenes in which a cop and his ex-partner are tracking down some criminals, they are approaching their spaceship, and they plan to arrest them. One of the cops enters another smaller ship than the one they are currently on and says:

"*We should split, I'll **come around** from the other side*.

Which of the following definitions fits here?
If none, what is the right definition, and which part of this sentence is a phrasal verb?

**Come around**

1. To take a curved or circular route.
   *Once you come around the bend, you'll be able to see the city in the distance*.
2. To avoid something.
   *I came around the block to avoid the house with the scary dog*.

Comment: It's closer to definition one.  He's saying they should split up so they can surround the criminals on two sides.  Whoever said this will go around the back of the ship to avoid being seen as they position themselves on the opposite side of the criminals.  The partner stays where he is, and so from his perspective the other partner has *come* back into view by going *around* the ship.

Comment: The path the partner who "comes around" makes is "U" shaped, having a bend in it as definition 1 states.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The most accurate definition is the first one: to take a curved or circular route.

Since they are splitting up (going in different directions), they will return by "coming around" from the other side. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Daydream@ As I understand it, it means that, because he will be talking a circular route(in a U-shape as mjjf@ suggested) he will come around that last bend in the back of the ship of those criminals they are chasing.

Comment: @StaticBounce yes that's correct!